# Meteor x Modulus Spiderable/PhantomJS issue

Tags: ajax, meteor, web-crawler

I am reading a ton of things on this issue but can't figure out the answer. 
I am on hosting our app on Modulus. I am using `ongoworks:spiderable` and `dfischer:phantomjs` and getting the following error.

```
spiderable: phantomjs failed: Error: Command failed: 
  at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:658:15)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5) 
stderr:
```

Since [Google depreciated their AJAX crawling](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) I really want to figure out how to fix this bug and move on.

Also, how do I test if my app is crawlable now since `?_escaped_fragment_=` doesn't do anything anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified that phantomjs is installed properly? Run `phantomjs --version` at the command line. If that works, check to make sure you have the ROOT_URL correctly set up in your config file.

Comment: both are set up correctly, before I was able to go to `mywebsite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=` and see the crawled content in `<body></body>` even though I was getting the same error @BrianShamblen